# Reading from STDIN pipe when using proc_open

Tags: php, proc-open

I am trying to make a website where people can compile and run their code online, thus we need to find an interactive way for users to send instructions.

Actually, what first comes to mind is `exec()` or `system()`, but when users want to input sth, this way won't work. So we have to use `proc_open()`.

For instance, the following code

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("please input a integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Hello World %d!\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

When I used `proc_open()`, like this

```
$descriptorspec = array(      
0 => array( 'pipe' , 'r' ) ,  
    1 => array( 'pipe' , 'w' ) ,  
    2 => array( 'file' , 'errors' , 'w' ) 
);  
$run_string = "cd ".$addr_base."; ./a.out 2>&1";
$process = proc_open($run_string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if (is_resource($process)) {
    //echo fgets($pipes[1])."<br/>";
    fwrite($pipes[0], '12');
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    while (!feof($pipes[1]))
        echo fgets($pipes[1])."<br/>";
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($process);
}
```

When running the C code, I want to get the first STDOUT stream, and input the number, then get the second STDOUT stream. But if I have the commented line uncommented, the page will be blocked.

Is there a way to solve the problem? How can I read from the pipe while not all data has been put there? Or is there a better way to write this kind of interactive program?

Comment: Is your "user" interacting from website? Because by that way user does not seem to have direct access of your server's `STDIN`.

Comment: @Passerby The user presses a button to compile, and inputs _x_ and sends it to the server. But before he inputs _x_, the server has to get the stream from `STDIN` first and sends it to the website so that the user knows he should input _x_. The problem is the server cannot get the stream at that moment..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is more a `C` or a `glibc` problem. You'll have to use `fflush(stdout)`.

Why? And what's the difference between running `a.out` in a terminal and calling it from PHP?

Answer: If you run `a.out` in a terminal (being stdin a tty) then the glibc will use line buffered IO. But if you run it from another program (PHP in this case) and it's stdin is a pipe (or whatever but not a tty) than the glibc will use internal IO buffering. That's why  the first `fgets()` blocks if uncommented. For more info check this [article](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/).

Good news: You can control this buffering using the [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) command. Change `$run_string` to:

```
$run_string = "cd ".$addr_base.";stdbuf -o0 ./a.out 2>&1";
```

---

Here comes a working example. Working even if the C code don't cares about `fflush()` as it is using the `stdbuf` command:

Starting subprocess

```
$cmd = 'stdbuf -o0 ./a.out 2>&1';

// what pipes should be used for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR of the child
$descriptorspec = array (
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("pipe", "w")
 );

// open the child
$proc = proc_open (
    $cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, getcwd()
);
```

set all streams to non blocking mode

```
// set all streams to non blockin mode
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0);
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 0);

// check if opening has succeed
if($proc === FALSE){
    throw new Exception('Cannot execute child process');
}
```

get child pid. we need it later

```
// get PID via get_status call
$status = proc_get_status($proc);
if($status === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception (sprintf(
        'Failed to obtain status information '
    ));
}
$pid = $status['pid'];
```

poll until child terminates

```
// now, poll for childs termination
while(true) {
    // detect if the child has terminated - the php way
    $status = proc_get_status($proc);
    // check retval
    if($status === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception ("Failed to obtain status information for $pid");
    }
    if($status['running'] === FALSE) {
        $exitcode = $status['exitcode'];
        $pid = -1;
        echo "child exited with code: $exitcode\n";
        exit($exitcode);
    }

    // read from childs stdout and stderr
    // avoid *forever* blocking through using a time out (50000usec)
    foreach(array(1, 2) as $desc) {
        // check stdout for data
        $read = array($pipes[$desc]);
        $write = NULL;
        $except = NULL;
        $tv = 0;
        $utv = 50000;

        $n = stream_select($read, $write, $except, $tv, $utv);
        if($n > 0) {
            do {
                $data = fread($pipes[$desc], 8092);
                fwrite(STDOUT, $data);
            } while (strlen($data) > 0);
        }
    }


    $read = array(STDIN);
    $n = stream_select($read, $write, $except, $tv, $utv);
    if($n > 0) {
        $input = fread(STDIN, 8092);
        // inpput to program
        fwrite($pipes[0], $input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks~ But the C code is from the user, and he just presses `Enter` to compile and run. Is it possible to change some part of _test.php_ to make it work?

Comment: Interesting problem! :) Will investigate this.

Comment: I wonder if this works on Mac OSX? It shows `sh: stdbuf: command not found`. I will try on Ubuntu later!

Comment: thx a lot, it worked! but how can I tell whether everything in  `pipes[1]` has been read? when using `while(!feof($pipes[1]))`, it blocks again..

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw your comment before. Use non-blocking streams, see `stream_set_blocking()`. Also you'll have to use `proc_get_status()` and check for running state.

Comment: I used these codes, `stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);echo fgets($pipes[1]);`, it turned out nothing came out at all.. I don't know what went wrong..

Comment: have you tested my example?

Comment: Check my example. I'm using *blocking* sockets but `stream_select()` with a timeout of `50000 usec`. Try my example (have you realized that I gave a second example?)

Comment: can you send me full version of your example? Some errors just came out, so I edited some places but it blocked.. yeyh10@gmail.com

Comment: Its from a more complex class.. Just remove the `$this` and add the vars `$cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env,$otherOptions`... (You already have them)

Comment: I did as you said.. and I run the example in terminal but it seems to have no response to what I input..

Comment: Check my update. I have tested it and it worked ( With your unchanged C code)

Comment: Thats funny :) It works even with the `$cmd = 'stdbuf -o0 /bin/bash'` but without prompt (of course). Never tested it before.

Comment: This time it worked! Appreciate your help. I will try it on my project!

Comment: Holy guacamole. I have had this problem for a year now and this is the only working solution. I will dig into the code and try to better my understanding of sockets, pipes and all the like.

Comment: Just a quick update, I am using stdbuf -o0 with symfony/process (instead of the code above), and it works without any issues.

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan Yes, if you just call a single command `stdbuf -o0` is fine. The code above is meant to send multiple commands into the command's stdin.

Comment: @hek2mgl: I missed that point about stdin. But I was also using this snippet to do line by line processing, which symfony/process does. You can asynchronously process output line by line with a callback.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is surprisingly simple: leave `$descriptorspec` empty. If you do so, the child process will simply use the STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR streams of the parent.

```
➜  ~  ✗ cat stdout_is_atty.php
<?php

var_dump(stream_isatty(STDOUT));
➜  ~  ✗ php -r 'proc_close(proc_open("php stdout_is_atty.php", [], $pipes));'
/home/chx/stdout_is_atty.php:3:
bool(true)
➜  ~  ✗ php -r 'passthru("php stdout_is_atty.php");'
/home/chx/stdout_is_atty.php:3:
bool(false)
➜  ~  ✗ php -r 'exec("php stdout_is_atty.php", $output); print_r($output);'
Array
(
    [0] => /home/chx/stdout_is_atty.php:3:
    [1] => bool(false)
)
```

Credit goes to John Stevenson, one of the maintainers of composer.

If you are interested why this happens: PHP does nothing for empty descriptors and uses the C / OS defaults which just happens to be the desired one.

So the C code responsible for `proc_open` always merely iterates the descriptors. If there are no descriptors specified then all that code does nothing. After that, the actual execution of the child -- at least on POSIX systems -- happens via calling [`fork(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) which makes the child inherit file descriptors (see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278119/9452)). And then the child calls one of `execvp(3)` / `execle(3)` / `execl(3)` . And as the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execle) says

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

Perhaps it's more understandable to say the memory region containing the parent is replaced by the new program. This is accessible as `/proc/$pid/mem`, see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6302/9452) for more. However, the system keeps a tally of the opened files outside of this region. You can see them in `/proc/$pid/fd/` -- and STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR are just shorthands for file descriptors 0/1/2. So when the child replaces the memory, the file descriptors just stay in place.